# How to detect ngSwitch changes in Angular page

Tags: angular, dom, stripe-payments, angular-changedetection, ng-switch

Currently I am integrating Stripe into Angular. The implementation works fine until I started moving the Stripe Elements into an `ngSwitchCase` and `ng-container`

That's when I started getting this error:

```
ERROR IntegrationError: The selector you specified (#card-element) applies to no DOM elements 
that are currently on the page.
Make sure the element exists on the page before calling mount()
```

The reason is that stripe tries to `mount` the element before the `ngSwitchCase` shows up. I tried using `ngAfterViewInit` but it seems that the function is executed once when the component is rendered for the first time and not when `ngSwitch` changes the view.

Is there a way I can detect changes in the view of the component? That way I know when to `mount()` the Stripe elements after the component is completely rendered. Note below that I am using `ng-container` which do not adds DOM nodes to the HTML, according to the Angular docs.

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="selectedForm">
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'FORM_ONE'">
          <form>
              ...
          </form>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'FORM_TWO'">
          <form>
              ...
          </form>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'FORM_THREE'">
           // Stripe 'card-element'
          <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
              <label for="card-element">Credit or debit card</label>
              <div id="card-element"></div>
              <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
          </form>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the template add a name to the card

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'FORM_THREE'">
           // Stripe 'card-element'
          <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
              <label for="card-element">Credit or debit card</label>
              <div #stripeCard id="card-element"></div>
              <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
          </form>
  </ng-container>
```

now, you can be notified when rendered by using a setter.
in component:

```
 card:ElementRef;
 @ViewChild('stripeCard') set content(content: ElementRef) {
    if(content) { // initially setter gets called with undefined
         
        //mount it here...
     
       //for future reference...  
       this.card=content;
    }
 }
```